# Introspect the regex part that generated group in Python's 're'

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, introspection

Is there a way of figuring out the actual string (or... sub-regular-expression... or... "chunk" of the regular expression) that generated a named group in a compiled Pattern?

For instance, something along the lines of:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile("foo(?P<bar>\d+)")

# The following is what I don't know how to do:
>>> sub_r = r.somethingsomething('bar')
>>> print(sub_r)

'\\d+'
```

I know I can get the names of the groups using `r.groupindex` and that `r.pattern` would give me the original string the full regex came from, yet I don't know how to combine both ideas (and it feels there *must* be a way):

```
>>> r.groupindex
mappingproxy({'bar': 1})

>>> r.pattern
'foo(?P<bar>\\d+)'
```

Comment: Please check [Extract named group regex pattern from a compiled regex in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858357/extract-named-group-regex-pattern-from-a-compiled-regex-in-python)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, thank you. I guess I was hoping for something a bit more straight forward (and specially less error-prone) than trying to regex-analyze my regex **:-(** I'm kind of worried about complex patterns with many subgroups in it. I.e.: `(?P<bar>\d(\w+))`

Comment: I think you should build the pattern dynamically and fill the named group patterns with a dictionary where the key is the group name and the pattern is the value.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea, @WiktorStribiżew Though right now the pattern is coming as text from a file, so it's a tad hard to do what you're describing. I guess I'm trying to get the pattern _"after the fact"_, so to speak, but we'll see what we can do. **:-)** Thank you very much for the hints!!

Comment: In brief, you will have to roll out your regex parser, or find libraries that do that for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse regular expression from named group](/q/30688212/90527)

Comment: It certainly helps, @outis. If anything, I was looking for a more built-in way through the `re` module itself. But it is very helpful. Thank you!